# how to add a static member to thrust::binary_predicate?

Tags: cuda, thrust

I'm trying to add a static member to the following type:

```
struct mostRightCornerPred
{
    __host__ __device__ 
    static int numIterations;   
    bool operator()(const long long first,const long long seconds) const
    {
        return true;
    }

};
```

but I keep on getting an error:

```
1>c:\users\igal\desktop\pj1712 fixed map res\graph\types.h(21): error
: attribute "__host__" does not apply here
1>c:\users\igal\desktop\pj1712 fixed map res\graph\types.h(21): error
: memory qualifier on data member is not allowed
```

My guess is that CUDA can't refer to this member. How can I fix it?

Comment: That code is broken, surely that isn't what you are trying to compile?

Comment: `__host__ __device__` are intended for the operator aren't they? At the moment you are applying them to the static member.......

Comment: i want them to apply on the entire struct's members both static members and operator

Comment: `__host__` is only every applied to function definitions, never to variables. And a static data member must be *defined* outside of the class. How are you going to define a compilation unit scoped variable as `__host__ __device__`? That is illegal. And even if it were not illegal how could you access it from the class without huge memory races?

Comment: @igalk: This isn't possible. What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: Jared: Hey, i tried to use a binary predicate with an additional information, since the binary takes only 2 parameters i wanted to create a static variable which would hold the global information(double)

Comment: @igalk: If the state is constant, you can introduce a member variable, but you can't introduce shared mutable state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even looking past the syntax errors in your code, static data in **device** code is illegal. The reason is that there is no defined point at which it would be initialized, if all threads would do so, or if just one, and if so, which thread.  So static data just doesn't make sense in this context.

I believe this limitation is discussed in the CUDA programming guide.

If you want data members in a functor,  just add a constructor to your functor and initialize the data using an argument to the constructor.